# Cual es la mejor forma de hacer una web responsive, ¿con o sin emulación de dispositivos?

Tags: html, css

Cuando uso emulación de dispositivos algunas partes me aparecen con bugs pero ajustándolo desde la ventana de inspeccionar no aparecen, esto hace que la página se deforme en la emulacion de dispositivos, lo que quiero saber es que si al momento de subir esa página y una persona la ve desde un teléfono, ¿de que forma la va a ver? dejo imágenes para mejor explicación.
[image: con y sin emulacion de dispositivo]

Comment: Esas herramientas son útiles para diseñar en responsive, pero suelen ser limitadas para detectar ciertos problemas específicos en algunos dispositivos. Te recomiendo que utilices un dispositivo nativo para desarrollar y debbugear directamente ahí, y no es muy difícil hacerlo. Este articulo te explica cómo: [Debugging Responsive Design en tu teléfono](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/debugging-responsive-design-en-tu-telefono)